# Not getting custom headers in request object express js

Tags: express

Here is My code

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.header("auth-token","tokenstring").send("home")
})


app.get("/getheader",(req,res)=>{
   let token = req.headers['auth-token']
   console.log(token)
   res.send("whatever")
})
```

getting output undefined

`

Tried a lot but didn't find any solution

Comment: You have to re-send the token from the client via headers. Are you doing that? Maybe you are looking for cookies. You can use [express cookies](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cookie-parser.html). Instead of setting headers, set cookies on your root route and read them on a different route.

Comment: I want to set custom header and pass to another route

Comment: You have to re-send the token from the client via headers ..... no I'm not doing it .... is there any method to get headers route to route ?

Comment: I am not sure if you can read headers from the `render-view` request. You will probably have to make a HTTP request from the browser, record the header in some local state, then re-attach to the new API request. Since this is an auth-token, I don't think you should read it on the client side. Cookies would be a better fit for this.